# How to show/hide @foreach statement

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-blade

I have a Vuejs 3 dropdown reusable component. My problem is that the @foreach statement runs before the component loads so it causes a flash of the foreach results which is very ugly upon refresh or when the page is loading.

To demonstrate please check this gif:

[image: dropdown]

My component in blade:

```html
<Dropdown title="{{ isset($currentCategory) ? ucwords($currentCategory->name) : 'Categories' }}">

    <Dropdowncontent>

        <Dropdownitems href="/">
            All
        </Dropdownitems>

        <div>
            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                <Dropdownitems
                    href="/?category={{ $category->slug }}&{{ http_build_query(request()->except('category')) }}"
                    class="{{ isset($currentCategory) && $currentCategory->is($category) ? ' selectedCategoryItem' : '' }}">
                    {{ $category->name }}
                </Dropdownitems>
            @endforeach
        </div>

    </Dropdowncontent>

</Dropdown>
```

I added a div to contain the @foreach statement but i don't know what to do from here. I don't want to use alpineJS as it will defeat the purpose of using Vue (I guess?).

I just need a way to only display this div or the @foreach statement if the component is fully loaded or if the button is pressed or something like that. Any ideas?

-- EDIT --

I tried to hide the links in my 'dropdownitems' vue component and set the default value to false. The links are now hidden but still the blade @foreach statement echoing out the results as text before the component is loaded:

```html
<template>
    <a v-if="showLinks" href="" class="demogard categoryItems">
        <slot />
    </a>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Dropdownitems",
    setup() {
        const showLinks = false;

        return {
            showLinks,
        };
    },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Here is a gif to show the result of that:

[image: foreach2]

-- EDIT --

Here is my dropdown component:

```js
<template>
    <div
        class="relative"
        v-click-outside="onClickOutside"
        @click="showCategories"
    >
        <slot name="toggler">
            <button
                class="flex max-h-52 w-full overflow-auto py-2 pl-3 pr-9 text-sm font-semibold lg:inline-flex lg:w-32"
            >
                {{ title }}
            </button>
        </slot>

        <slot />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import vClickOutside from "click-outside-vue3";
import { ref, onMounted, provide } from "vue";
export default {
    name: "Dropdown",
    props: ["title"],
    directives: {
        clickOutside: vClickOutside.directive,
    },
    setup() {
        const sharedState = ref(false);

        const showCategories = () => {
            sharedState.value = !sharedState.value;
        };

        const onClickOutside = (event) => {
            sharedState.value = false;
        };

        provide("sharedState", sharedState);


        return {
            sharedState,
            showCategories,
            onClickOutside,
        };
    },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Comment: Have you tried with an "@if" directive:

Comment: Yes but if what? I mean 'show this is only if my component is loaded' or 'if the page fully loaded' ? how to write that :D

Comment: I edited the answer, you have to set the variable as false and change it in the mounted (or created) hook, i also left a link to the documentation

Comment: I edited the question to show what that led me to. i need to control the foreach statement not the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question, I think you have to add `if condition` on your dropdown component.

Your dropdown component should be like this

```
#dropdown.vue
<template>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div @click="show = !show">{{title}}</div>
        
        <div v-if="show">
            <slot />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
export default {
  props: ["title"],
  setup(props) {
    const show = ref(false);
    return {
      show,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-dropdown-0rxvo?file=/src/components/Dropdown.vue)

---- EDIT ----

```
#dropdown.vue
<template>
    <div
        class="relative"
        v-click-outside="sharedState = false"
    >
        <slot name="toggler">
            <button
                class="flex max-h-52 w-full overflow-auto py-2 pl-3 pr-9 text-sm font-semibold lg:inline-flex lg:w-32"
                @click="sharedState = !sharedState"
            >
                {{ title }}
            </button>
        </slot>
        <div v-if="sharedState">
            <slot />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import vClickOutside from "click-outside-vue3";
import { ref, onMounted, provide } from "vue";
export default {
    name: "Dropdown",
    props: ["title"],
    directives: {
        clickOutside: vClickOutside.directive,
    },
    setup() {
        const sharedState = ref(false);

        // const showCategories = () => {
        //     sharedState.value = !sharedState.value;
        // };

        // const onClickOutside = (event) => {
        //     sharedState.value = false;
        // };

        provide("sharedState", sharedState);

        return {
            sharedState,
            //showCategories,
            //onClickOutside,
        };
    },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Comment: It works in your code because you're not using @foreach in laravel blade. PHP code runs before Vue so that's why it flashes the foreach before vue with it's login renders. I can loop over the database within my vue component like you did and it will solve the issue but it defeats the whole purpose of having reusable dropdown vue component which means if i need to use this dropdown component somewhere else i will have to duplicate the component to loop over something else. I believe I have only 2 options. 1- Forget about vue and use laravel and alpineJS. 2- hard code the links not loop over it

Comment: Can you share your `dropdown` component?

Comment: edited in the question

Comment: I have change in you code try it out

Answer (score 0):

Try with a @if directive:

[Conditional Rendering](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html#v-if)

from the documentation:

```
<button @click="awesome = !awesome">Toggle</button>

<h1 v-if="awesome">Vue is awesome!</h1>
<h1 v-else>Oh no </h1>
```

As showed in the example it render the "h1" tag conditionally respect the "awesome" variable.
In this case i will set a default value of "false" and i will turn it to "true" in the mounted hook:

[Lifecycle](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Do you mean within my vue component only show the anchor tags if the button is clicked and set the default value to false? Because of so, the foreach statement is echoing out the categories before even it knows that there is an anchor tag.

Comment: I mean that my dropdown works and it only shows the content which contains the links when the button is pressed. but from the blade side before all of this happens it flashes out the foreach results as text

Comment: I've edited the question to demonstrate what it led me to ..

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to load Vue before PHP because your webpage only displays when full PHP code is received from the server. Therefore, we're never able to stop PHP or HTML from flashing if we're using them inside a reusable Vue component.

The solution I made is simply passing the value of the foreach loop as a prop to the Vue component in order for it to be displayed from there, not from my blade file.

Here's my code in blade after passing the value of the category name as a prop to my Vue component.

```html
<Dropdown title="{{ isset($currentCategory) ? ucwords($currentCategory->name) : 'Categories' }}">

    <Dropdowncontent>

        <Dropdownitems href="/" category="All"></Dropdownitems>

        @foreach ($categories as $category)
            <Dropdownitems 
                category="{{ $category->name }}"
                href="/?category={{ $category->slug }}&{{ http_build_query(request()->except('category')) }}"
                class="{{ isset($currentCategory) && $currentCategory->is($category) ? ' selectedCategoryItem' : '' }}">
            </Dropdownitems>
        @endforeach

    </Dropdowncontent>

</Dropdown>
```

Here is me displaying it from there the Vue dropdown items component:

```js
<template>
    <a href="" class="demogard categoryItems">
        <slot>{{ category }}</slot>
    </a>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Dropdownitems",
    props: ["category"],
};
</script>

<style></style>
```